# refactor my array sorting function

Tags: java, algorithm

So, how to make it more compact?

```
   public static boolean isDirectOrder( int[] data )
   {
      boolean answer = true;

      if ( ( data != null ) && ( data.length > 1 ) )
      {
         int last = data[0];

         for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
         {
            if ( last <= data[i] )
            {
               last = data[i];
            }
            else
            {
               answer = false;
               break;
            }
         }
      }

      return answer;
   }
```

maybe exist standard tools for same checking?

Comment: TIP: If you are checking the array to see if you need it sort it, it is easier to sort it anyways. This is also the main reason, API developers would probably not implement a library function to check for sorted order.

Comment: Sanjit: One possible use for this function is for a method that has to do lots of lookups on a large array. If it's in order, it can just do a binary search of the array. If not, it has to do linear searches. The method can't just sort the list because that would change the indices of all the values.

Comment: @Gabe if we can remember that information between searches, sure. Otherwise we're looking at every element of the array in order to determine whether or not we have to look at every element of the array :/ And if we can remember that information (i.e. elements won't be inserted or removed) then (a) why is the order so important and (b) why don't we construct some kind of index?

Comment: Karl: By all means, rename this method to be `isIndexNeeded` instead of `isDirectOrder`.

Comment: what are you doing??? I am not argee with new title of my question!!!! rename title!!!!

Answer (score 4):

```
public static boolean isDirectOrder( int[] data )
{
    if (data != null)
        for (int i = 1; i < data.length; i++)
            if (data[i] < data[i - 1])
                return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: `(data[i] <= data[i - 1])`?? From OPs Question,I think Consecutive equal elements are allowed...

Comment: st0le: Did you mean to comment on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481660/refactor-my-array-sorting-function/4481688#4481688?

Comment: @Gabe, No, i meant you...shouldn't it be `(data[i] <= data[i - 1])`

Comment: st0le: No, if you put the `=` in there, it would return `false` if two consecutive elements were equal, which is not the expected behavior.

Comment: @Gabe, why would you say that? Duplicate elements are possible, the OP's original code does consider (attempts to, anyway) duplicate elements...

Comment: st0le: What are you talking about? The OP's `last <= data[i]` is exactly equivalent to my `data[i] < data[i - 1]`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this (not tested).

```
public static boolean isDirectOrder( int[] data )
{
    if ((data != null))
    {
       for (int i = 1; i < data.length; i++)
       {
           if (data[i] <= data[i - 1])
               return false;
       }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class A {
  public static boolean isDirectedOrder(int[] d) {
    if (d == null) return true;
    for (int i = 0, l = d.length - 1; i < l; i ++) if (d[i] > d[i + 1]) return false;
    return true;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(isDirectedOrder(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10 }));
    System.out.println(isDirectedOrder(new int[] { 1 }));
    System.out.println(isDirectedOrder(new int[] { 3, 2, 5, 1, 5, 7 }));
  }
}
```

Comment: Your function crashes if passed in `null`.

Comment: @Gabe that's normal, null check should be done separately, like other Java standard API's did

Comment: SHiNKiROU: The OP's function returns `true` when `null` gets passed in, while yours crashes. That's a pretty big difference.

Answer (score 0):

It looks pretty compact to me. You're trying to find if the array is already sorted. You could remove your braces for some if statements:

```
if ( last <= data[i] )
{
last = data[i];
}
```

could become

```
if ( last <= data[i] )
   last = data[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit unlogic to return true when `data == null`.

```
public static boolean isDirectOrder( int[] data )
{
    if (data == null)
         throw new NullPointerException("Array is null");
    for (int i = 1; i < data.length; ++i)
        if (data[i] < data[i - 1]) // When this one is smaller than the previous one.
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

And, in fact, the statement `data.length` will throw a NullPointerException as well:

```
public static boolean isDirectOrder( int[] data )
{
    for (int i = 1; i < data.length; ++i)
        if (data[i] < data[i - 1])
            return false;

    return true;
}
```